# RichFaces ajax don't work

Tags: ajax, richfaces

I am trying use the sample from showcase of commandButton.

But when I do this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Rich Teste</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet>
            form {
                background: #fee3ad
            }
        </h:outputStylesheet>
        <h:form id="iddoform" >
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Nome:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{testeBean.nome}"/>
                <a4j:commandButton  value="Teste" render="iddoform:out" execute="@form" />
            </h:panelGrid>
           <br />
           <a4j:outputPanel id="out">
                <h:outputText value="Hello #{testeBean.nome} !"/>
           </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
        <br />
        <a4j:log /> 
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

It didn't work, so I changed to this:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:outputStylesheet>
        form {
            background: #fee3ad
        }
    </h:outputStylesheet>

    <h:form id="iddoform">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Nome:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{testeBean.nome}" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Teste"
                render="iddoform:out" execute="@form" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br />
        <a4j:outputPanel id="out">
            <h:outputText value="Hello #{testeBean.nome} !" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
    </html>
enter code here
```

And it works!

The change was to remove the head and body from html.

**My question is:** 'Why doesn't work with head and body tags?'.

PS: I am try with render="iddoform:out", :iddoform:out and out; And i am try with immediate true too, but dont work.

Comment: Please post code here and not links. If links die your question will be useless.

Comment: Thank you Sergio, the next time i'am post the code.

Comment: The sample of test on git: https://github.com/levymoreira/RichTeste/ case everyone wants test.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work" you have to say how are you expecting it to work.

It's not the `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` that makes it not work, it's the `immediate="true"`. It makes the button action be processed before the name can be set. You don't have it in your second example, that's why it works.

Also you don't have to use `iddoform:out` to point to the panel, just `out` is enough, the engine will find it.

Comment: Hi Makhiel, iam try with out imediate, and with 'iddoform:out', ':iddoform:out' and 'out' but only worked when I removed the head and body. If you download the github project you see, the sample in github.com/levymoreira/RichTeste is worked, but if you add head and body dont work. Thank you. PS: Iam edit the original ask for improve understanding.

Comment: @LevyMoreira when I copy the first example it works for me. What is not working for you? Is the text not being refreshed?

Comment: Yes he works, now add head and body tags and he dont work more.